# Sony STR-DN1080 how to wake up from network?

Tags: sony

How can we wake-up from network (from phone application or from home network automation system) the STR-DN1080 ? 
It seems such feature is possible in the USA and Canada, but that it's disabled in Europe : I see in FAQs that, in Network Settings, the settings for keeping netwotk functions in stand by is disabled in Europe !
Why is it so ?
How to switch on the AVR in Europe ? If you must go to the avr first to switch it on, the phone applications become useless..
Another question then : could I load a USA firmware instead of my European one ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to send a [WoL message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) to wake the AVR in Europe.

It due to EU regulations and you can't load US firmware on AVR created for the EU market.

see [setPowerStatus](https://developer.sony.com/develop/audio-control-api/api-references/api-overview-2#_setpowerstatus_v1_1)

Comment: Hi, thank you for this explanation. I tried to wake it with WOL packets, but it does not  work. It's a European model, connected with LAN cable (RJ45 Cat6) and in NW settings I enabled "auto home Network Access permission" and "external control". But once in stand-by, WOL doesn't wake up the STR DN1080 (wherease it's a feature I use for some other computers of my network). (I checked MAC address of course and STR's NW diagnostic is ok). FW version is M41.R.0442. Would you have any advice ? Am I missing a setting somewhere ?

Comment: I have also another question: in stand by mode, when I enable the setting "Standby Through", my STR DN1080 consumes 44 to 50W, even in standby, even if no other device is switched on (the input DVD player and TV are in stand by). THis is huge consumption: can you tell me if it's normal ? (I'd expect 5 or 10W, but not 44W..)

Comment: I know the WoL can be a bit tricky to get working, usually I can connect to the web service and send the setPowerStatus message directly "even to EU models" and don't bother with WoL.

I also can't wake any of the audio devices with the built in WoL tool in my router.

Comment: That power consumption sounds very hi to me in the manual from the uk state the stand by power to 0.4W or 1.5 W if all ports connected. But I'm not a hardware guy :-)

I had one sound bar started to behave strange for me and never powered down (got really hot) had to factory reset it...

Comment: I tried to send curl requests instead of WOL, but it doesn't seem to work (provided I do it properly). I used a raspberry pi with : curl -i -d '{"method": "setPowerStatus","id": 65,"params": ['"status":"active"}],"version": "1.1"}' http://192.168.0.27:10000/sony/system
But no answer at all. Whereas if I do curl -i -d '{"method":,"version": "1.1"}' http://192.168.0.27:10000/sony/system then I got an answer (before putting it on stand by of course). Anything else I can try ? or with WOL (as API reference reminds that setpowerstatus does not work in Europe.

Comment: As a alternative to wake up STR DN1080 EU model Bluetooth can be used see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54765254/9444870

Comment: Wake On LAN requires "Remote Start" to be enabled on the receiver. This feature is apparently *not* supported on EU models: https://helpguide.sony.net/ha/strdn108/v1/en/contents/TP0001221408.html